# Unable to install ClamAV on 14.04 Ubuntu

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation

I am struggling with Clamav, no matter what I do I get an error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package clamav is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package 'clamav' has no installation candidate
```

I tried

```
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

then

```
sudo apt-get install clamav
```

then

```
sudo apt-get install clamav clamtk
```

than from the Software Center, but no luck.

Can someone please help me to install ClamAV?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy clamav clamtk`.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that all repositories are enabled.

```
sudo add-apt-repository main
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo add-apt-repository multiverse
sudo add-apt-repository restricted
```

Update the sources and install the packages.

```
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install clamav clamtk
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I followed your commands and it worked.